# How keras calculate loss if you have multiple output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I searched all over the web but I couldn't find it. how does Keras calculate the loss if we have multiple output values.

Comment: I googled "keras model multiple outputs" and this is literally right in the official docs. https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#models-with-multiple-inputs-and-outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which loss function you are using.
Usually, For each batch during training, Keras will call the
loss function to compute the loss and use it to perform a Gradient
Descent step. Moreover, it will keep track of the total loss since the
beginning of the epoch, and it will display the mean loss.

Regarding multiple outputs, same process happens and calculation wise you can pick any loss function mentioned in the document [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses) and check the examples.
Let's say for SparseCategoricalCrossentropy you can check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) document.